# Non-exhaustive patterns in function safetail

Tags: haskell

What is wrong with my code?

```
safetail (x:xs)= if null []==True then  xs else  error "Empty"
```

When I run my code it shows me an exception:

> ```
> Input safetail []
> *** Exception: safetail.hs:1:1-62: Non-exhaustive patterns in function safetail
> ```

Comment: The pattern `(x:xs)` will assign the first element to `x` and the tail of the cons list to `xs`. When the list is empty, it will not match because there is no first element.

Comment: `null []` is always true, since the empty list is, well, the empty list.

Comment: ok ,but when i run this code no problem , I want to tell me the list empty when running this code  (safetail []) , while not tell me empty, show me exception why?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use two cases; the pattern match is preventing your function from even being *called* (successfully) on an empty list.

```
safetail [] = error "Empty"
safetail (_:xs) = xs
```

That said, there's a certain amount of irony to a function with "safe" in its name raising a runtime exception. Either return an empty list

```
safetail :: [a] -> [a]
safetail [] = []
safetail (_:xs) = xs
```

or change your function type to make it total. E.g.,

```
safetail :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
safetail [] = Nothing
safetail (_:xs) = Just xs
```

Comment: thank you, my bro, for your helping, very useful